# Datomic audit log and enums

Tags: clojure, datomic

Given a query like this:

```
(def query '[:find ?tx ?date ?v ?op
 :in $ ?e ?a
 :where
 [?e ?a ?v ?tx ?op]
 [?tx :db/txInstant ?date]])
```

Where the entity and the attribute are being user provided, I can make a feature where I have an audit log on a per field basis. This works well.

My problem is enum fields. The `?v` that comes back is a `:db/id`, not the enum value itself, and I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to figure out that the field the user provided was an enum field and I should treat the `Long` value returned as a reference to an enum.

I think what I need to do is make the query return the `:db/valueType` for the attribute in question, and then if it's a `ref` type look up the entity that it points to. But I'm not sure if thats the right approach, or even how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working. I noticed that there is a `(d/attribute db atto-key)` function available in datomic, that will return the metadata fields about the attribute. So I can use that to check `:db/valueType` being equal to `:db/ref` and then call `(d/ident db entity-id)` to resolve the entity id down to its enum value.

Comment: You can also query the attribute directly via a clause `[?a :db/valueType ?vtid] [?vtid :db/ident ?vt]`

Comment: Attributes are stored and can be queried like all other entities - They aren't really meta-data.